# How to denoise audio with SOX?

Tags: audio-recording, sox

Given a audio.wav recording with silence at both start and end for at least 1second...

**How to denoise with SOX ?**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### What is SOX

- [SoX](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox) - Sound eXchange, the Swiss Army knife of audio manipulation

#### Create noise file from input audio's initial 0.9s silence + room's noise

```
# sox in.ext out.ext trim {start: s.ms} {duration: s.ms}
sox audio.wav noise-audio.wav trim 0 0.900
```

#### Generate a noise profile in sox:

```
sox noise-audio.wav -n noiseprof noise.prof
```

#### Clean the noise from the audio

```
sox audio.wav audio-clean.wav noisered noise.prof 0.21
```

According to source :

> Change 0.21 to adjust the level of sensitivity in the sampling rates (I found 0.2-0.3 often provides best result).

#### Sources

- [How To Do Noise Reduction Using ffmpeg And sox](http://www.zoharbabin.com/how-to-do-noise-reduction-using-ffmpeg-and-sox/)

Comment: I get: `sox FAIL noisered: multi-channel effect drained asymmetrically!`

Comment: @funerr you need to make sure both the input sound and the noise wav files are mono first. You can convert them with any of these 2 commands:
`sox sample_en_with_background_noise.wav sample_en_with_background_noise_1ch.wav remix 1` or

`ffmpeg -i stereo.wav -af "pan=mono|FC=FR" stereo_mono.wav`